# NAT (Redirect) outgoing traffic to a specific port

Tags: erlang, port, iptables, diameter-protocol

I'm trying to establish a connection with a diameter server. That server has a restriction parameter of "peer port"

Which means source port of my outgoing traffic should be restricted to a specific port.

Since I'm using an erlang diameter client, I didn't find any parameter to specify the outgoing port. It will initiate the connection with a random port to the destination ip:port.

Is there a way to translate my outgoing traffic to that ip locally to a specific port from linux?, so that the external server will see my source port as the allowed port.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a NAT at the sender side. Read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470436/iptables-nat-and-masquerade-rules-what-do-they-do), it explains how to do it with `iptables`.