# Iptables NAT and Masquerade rules - what do they do?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iptables

i've followed a [tutorial](https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2002171.htm) (in german) on setting up a WiFi Router (Access Point) on a Raspberry Pi. Following the tutorial i had to add the following iptable rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Unfortunately i dont have any experience with iptables and would like to know what the rules mean/do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I go through the rules, and explain each at once: for understanding the flow, refer to the [iptables chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

In the `FORWARD` chain, you appended a rule which says: if any packet comes newly, from `wlan0` to `eth0`, the filter lets it pass, and tracks that connection as `NEW` (which means: follows its change of state).

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

For any packets coming, tracked as `ESTABLISHED` or `RELATED`, the filter lets it pass

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

For the `NAT` table (which contains the `FORWARD` chain), in the `POSROUTING` chain, any packet leaving `eth0` forgets its inner IP address (so, stays behind a NAT), and gets the one of `eth0`: `MASQUERADE` stands for masking the address.

Comment: There's more to MASQUERADE than that.  It also gets a newly allocated port in addition to the address, and the tracker DOES NOT forget the original port and address.  Instead, any packet that come back to the (newly allocated) port is rewritten to go back to the original port and address.

Comment: Well said, Chris Dodd: you raised an important fact on `MASQUERADE`.